# Handlebars appends 'undefined' on a helper output

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have this helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('star-score', function(score, maxScore, options) {
    var output;

    for(var i = 1; i <= maxScore; i++) {
        if (score >= i) {
            output = output + '<span class="star full">&nbsp;</span>';
        } else {
            output = output + '<span class="star empty">&nbsp;</span>';
        }
    }

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);
});
```

Basically what I want to do is pass this helper some numbers and I want it to generate user rating stars based on numerical score

This is how I call this helper

```
<div class="user-score">
    {{star-score establishment.user_score 5}}
</div>
```

But what is interesting is that the resulted code looks like this

```
<div class="user-score">
    undefined
    <span class="star full">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="star full">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="star full">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="star empty">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="star empty">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

I have no clue where this "undefined" is coming from. And I have no clue how to troubleshoot it. There are no errors in the developer console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try setting output as an empty string first `var output = ""`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Good lesson about always initializing variables. Thanks!

Comment: ill make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time the loop runs output is `undefined` and so it evaluates as the following

```
output = undefined + '<span class="star full">&nbsp;</span>';
```

Just initialize output as an empty string to fix the problem

```
var output = "";
```